# Orbeon Forms: Check if Single Checkboxes are Active

Tags: orbeon

We have a requirement to have several ***single checkbox*** options with a corresponding text box for each checkbox (see this [demo form](https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/daccf9e40ef005136ee151fe25f7089e9bcadaee))

However, we want to stop the form being submitted unless one of these checkboxes has been selected.

[image]

We have tried various xPath options in the in the ***Validations & Alerts*** tab, but we have not had any luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have 3 such Single Checkbox fields, named `a`, `b`, and `c`. One way to handle this is to have, on each of those, the following validation rule:

```
$a/string() = 'true' or 
$b/string() = 'true' or 
$c/string() = 'true'
```

This would give:

[image: Testing 3 single checkboxes]

Comment: Thanks Alex, this works great thanks. W